# Regex not containing specific words (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP and I want to validate an email that must use either `.com`, `.co.id` or `.net`. Another domain would be considered as false.

I have tried this code :

```
preg_match("/[^\.com|\.co\.id|\.net]$/",$to);
```

But it doesn't work...
Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
preg_match("/\.(?:com|co\.id|net)$/", $to);
```

- escape the dot `\.`
- use a non-capture group instead of a character class.
- remove the anchor `^`

Comment: does non-capture group always start with ?: ?

Comment: @SalacceoVanz: Yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not understand well what a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) is. You can use a non capturing group:

```
preg_match("/\.(?:com|co\.id|net)$/", $to)
```